# Bouncing Over Animation - Looping

Tags: css, css-animations

So, I've been playing around with CSS recently and I wanted to make some kind of loader and I wanted one ball jumping over another.

I think the main challenge is the loop and returning the balls to starting position.

I managed to do this one here - https://codepen.io/nathanmrtns/pen/LYgGZyx, but I'm not really happy with the 'move' animation where they go back to the starting position.

Is there a better way to achieve that?

```html
<div class="loader">
  <div class="left"></div>
  <div class="left whiteline"></div>
  <div class="left outerline"></div>
  
  <div class="right"></div>
  <div class="right whiteline"></div>
  <div class="right outerline"></div>
</div>
```

```scss
$blue: #0069b4;

$loader-height: 440px;
$loader-width: 410px;

$left-circle-dimmension: 80px; //calc(#{$loader-height} - 30px);
$right-circle-dimmension: 100px; //calc(#{$loader-height} - 10px);

$animation-duration: 1s;

.loader {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  overflow: hidden;
  // background-color: orange;
  height: $loader-height;
  width: $loader-width;
}

@keyframes squeeze {
  0% {
    height: $left-circle-dimmension
  }
  40% {
    height: calc(#{$left-circle-dimmension} - 8px);
  }

  45%, 100% {
    height: $left-circle-dimmension;
  }
}

@keyframes squeeze-big {
  0% {
    height: $right-circle-dimmension
  }
  10% {
    height: calc(#{$right-circle-dimmension} - 8px);
  }
  15%, 100% {
    height: $right-circle-dimmension;
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  0%, 30% {
    left: 0;
  }
  100% {
    left: -40%;
  }
}


@keyframes move-big {
  0% {
    left: 30%;
  }

  70%, 100% {
    left: 0%;
  }
}

@keyframes bounce {
  0% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  30%, 100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}

@keyframes bounce-big {
  0%, 70% {
    transform: rotate(0);
  }
  100% {
    transform: rotate(180deg);
  }
}


.base-circle {
  background-color: $blue;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  margin: 10px;
}

.left {
  @extend .base-circle;
  transform-origin: 160%;
  height: $left-circle-dimmension;
  width: $left-circle-dimmension;
  bottom: 10px;
  z-index: 20;
  animation-direction: alternate;
  animation: bounce $animation-duration ease-in infinite, 
    move $animation-duration ease-in infinite,
    squeeze $animation-duration  ease-in infinite,
    ;
}

.right {
  @extend .base-circle;
  left: 20%;
  bottom: 0;
  transform-origin: 110%;
  height: $right-circle-dimmension;
  width: $right-circle-dimmension;
  z-index: 10;
  animation: bounce-big $animation-duration ease-in infinite,
    move-big $animation-duration ease-in infinite,
    squeeze-big $animation-duration ease-in infinite;
}

.whiteline {
  z-index: 5;
}

.whiteline::after {
  content: "";
  inset: 0px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  outline: solid 3px white;
}

.outerline {
  z-index: 4;
}

.outerline::after {
  content: "";
  inset: 0;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  outline: solid 6px $blue;
}
```